# InterruptedException thrown from futures

Tags: java, polling, scheduledexecutorservice, interrupted-exception

Suppose I have a method as follows:

```
public void poll(Callable<Boolean> callable) {
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadedScheduledExecutor();

    Future<Boolean> future = service.schedule(callable, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    try {
        while (!future.get()) {
            future = service.schedule(callable, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

How does an `InterruptedException` ever get thrown (and caught in `poll()`)?  Anything thrown by the callable (including `InterruptedException`, right?) would be an `ExecutionException`, we never cancel any futures, and the service's `shutdownNow()` is never called.

Aside: being what it is, is it possible to make this polling method more bulletproof against things like `InterruptedException`?

Answer (score 0):

The `InterruptedException` would be thrown by `get` while waiting (blocking) for the callable to finish.

I'm not sure what you mean by bulletproof, you have to handle the possibility of the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

InterruptedException can be thrown by the thread which called get and is waiting for completion, not by the callable